# Transferring Data by SMO failing when using ObjectList

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, smo

I can transfer all data from a source DB to a target DB by using the option CopyAllTables = true and not   providing a list in ObjectList.

```
            ServerConnection conn = new ServerConnection(sourceServer);
            conn.LoginSecure = true;
            Server srvSource = new Server(conn);
            Database dbSource = srvSource.Databases[sourceDB];

            Transfer xfr = new Transfer(dbSource);

            xfr.CopyAllTables = true;
            xfr.Options.WithDependencies = false;
            xfr.Options.ContinueScriptingOnError = false;
            xfr.DestinationDatabase = destDB;
            xfr.DestinationServer = destServer;
            xfr.Options.DriAllKeys = true;
            xfr.Options.DriForeignKeys = true;
            xfr.DestinationLoginSecure = true;

            xfr.CopySchema = false;
            xfr.CopyData = true;
            xfr.TransferData();
```

This works and all data get copied to the target DB. I need exclude one table from the copy process. I tried

```
            ServerConnection conn = new ServerConnection(sourceServer);
            conn.LoginSecure = true;
            Server srvSource = new Server(conn);
            Database dbSource = srvSource.Databases[sourceDB];

            Transfer xfr = new Transfer(dbSource);

            xfr.CopyAllTables = false;
            xfr.Options.WithDependencies = false;
            xfr.Options.ContinueScriptingOnError = false;
            xfr.DestinationDatabase = destDB;
            xfr.DestinationServer = destServer;
            xfr.Options.DriAllKeys = true;
            xfr.Options.DriForeignKeys = true;
            xfr.DestinationLoginSecure = true;

             foreach (Table tb in dbSource.Tables)
            {
                if (tb.IsSystemObject == false && tb.Name != "ExcludedTable" )
                {
                    xfr.ObjectList.Add(tb);
                }
            }

            xfr.CopySchema = false;
            xfr.CopyData = true;
            xfr.TransferData();
```

When TransferData is called I get an Exception "System.NullReferenceException" and no data is transfered

```
{"Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt."}
    [System.NullReferenceException]: {"Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt."}
    Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    HelpLink: null
    HResult: -2147467261
    InnerException: null
    Message: "Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt."
    Source: "Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended"
    StackTrace: "   bei Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Transfer.GetObjectList()\r\n   
    bei Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Transfer.Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ITransferMetadataProvider.SaveMetadata()\r\n 
    bei Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Dts.DtsTransferProvider.Configure(ITransferMetadataProvider metadataProvider)\r\n  
    bei Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Transfer.GetTransferProvider()\r\n   
    bei Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Transfer.TransferData()\r\n  

    TargetSite: {Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DependencyCollection GetObjectList()}
```

How can I exclude "ExcludedTable" from the export?

Comment: Hard to see what the exception is saying, it's in German and it doesn't refer to any line in your code where the exception is coming from. Any chance you could get that exception in English with proper indication where the exception originates?

Comment: @TT It is just `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` You can translate on http://www.finderr.net.

Comment: Try setting also `xfr.CopyAllObjects = false;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Except `xfr.CopyAllTables = false;` you must also set:

```
xfr.CopyAllObjects = false;
```

It is set by  default to `true` and that is the reason for the error you get.
If you omit this line you get exactly the null reference exception that you mention.

(Verified your code and working with 110\SDK\Assemblies)