# Using SMO to copy duplicate a database but not transfer all data

Tags: c#, smo

I need to duplicate database and transfer the data of specific table only but I dont know how to do it in SMO

currently here's what I have:

```
try
{
    if (isFromConsole)
        Console.WriteLine("Initializing database creation...");

    var srcDbInfo = GetInfo(srcConnectionString);
    var destDbInfo = GetInfo(destConnectionString);


    var sc = new ServerConnection();
    sc.LoginSecure = false;
    sc.ServerInstance = srcDbInfo.DataSource;
    sc.Login = srcDbInfo.UserID;
    sc.Password = srcDbInfo.Password;
    sc.ConnectTimeout = 0;
    sc.StatementTimeout = 0;

    sc.Connect();

    if (sc.IsOpen)
    {
        Server server = new Server(sc);

        Database srcDb = server.Databases[srcDbInfo.DBName];
        Database destDb = new Database(server, destDbInfo.DBName);

        // Create method will create the database on the specified server 
        if (isFromConsole)
            Console.WriteLine("Creating Database...");
        destDb.Create();

        if (isFromConsole)
            Console.WriteLine("Database successfully created...");

        //Create an object of Transfer class and pass
        //reference of source database to its construtor 
        Transfer transfer = new Transfer(srcDb);
        transfer.Options.WithDependencies = true;
        transfer.Options.ContinueScriptingOnError = true;
        // set copy options
        transfer.CopyAllObjects = true;
        transfer.CopyAllSchemas = true;
        //Copy all user defined data types from source to destination 
        transfer.CopyAllUserDefinedDataTypes = true;
        //Copy all tables from source to destination
        transfer.CopyAllTables = true;
        //Copy data of all source tables to destination tables 
        //It actually generates INSERT statement for destination 
        transfer.CopyData = true;
        //Copy all stored procedure from source to destination 
        transfer.CopyAllStoredProcedures = true;
        //set reference to all
        transfer.Options.DriAll = true;
        //specify the destination server name 
        transfer.DestinationServer = server.Name;
        //specify the destination database name and credentials
        transfer.DestinationDatabase = destDb.Name;
        transfer.DestinationLoginSecure = false;
        transfer.DestinationLogin = destDbInfo.UserID;
        transfer.DestinationPassword = destDbInfo.Password;


        //TransferData method transfers the schema objects and data 
        //whatever you have specified to destination database 
        if (isFromConsole)
            Console.WriteLine("Transferring data...");
        transfer.TransferData();


        if (isFromConsole)
            Console.WriteLine("Transfer completed...");
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

This code duplicates and transfers all data from the source database. I need to have set all the tables that I want to copy all the data in it but I don't know how and I can't see any documentation of it.

Comment: if you are using SQL Server Management the simple way is to deattach the database copy the mdf and ldf files.  The reattach the original database.  Then attach the copy under a different name.  This will copy everything.  You can then delete what you do not want.

Comment: Take a look at the ObjectList and make sure to set CopyAllObjects to false https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26259512/transferring-data-by-smo-failing-when-using-objectlist

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method I converted from VB.NET (from my GitHub repository), see if this would work for you

https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/LearningSMObasicsWithVisualBasic/blob/master/SMO_UtilityLibrary/Classes/DatabaseInformation.vb#L34

```
/// <summary>
/// Copy database to new database on same server
/// </summary>
/// <param name="pOriginalDatabase">Database to copy</param>
/// <param name="pNewDatabase">Copy to database with unique database name</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public bool CopyDatabase(string pOriginalDatabase, string pNewDatabase)
{

    var srv = new Server();
    Database db = null;

    db = srv.Databases[pOriginalDatabase];
    Database dbCopy = null;
    dbCopy = new Database(srv, pNewDatabase);
    dbCopy.Create();

    Transfer trans = null;
    trans = new Transfer(db)
    {
        CopyAllTables = false,
        Options =
            {
                WithDependencies = true,
                ContinueScriptingOnError = true
            },
        DestinationDatabase = pNewDatabase,
        DestinationServer = srv.Name,
        DestinationLoginSecure = true
    };
    trans.Options.DriAllKeys = true;
    trans.CopySchema = true;

    trans.TransferData();

    return true;

}
```

See also
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.transfer?view=sql-smo-140.17283.0

**EDIT** I just noticed that you want specific table, what I posted "as is" copies no data, only structure so it may not provide what you are looking for.

Comment: I want to copy all tables but the table with data is only specific

Comment: where is the ServerConnection ConnectionString in that function?
 ServerConnection srvCon = new ServerConnection(conn);
                    Server serv = new Server(srvCon);

Comment: See the following [code](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/LearningSMObasicsWithVisualBasic/blob/master/SMO_UtilityLibrary/Classes/DatabaseInformation.vb#L87)